# CakePHP 3.x Routing with slug

Tags: redirect, cakephp, url-routing

In CakePHP 3.x I am trying to set correct routing from the old page with the old slug into the new page with the new slug. The old page is removed and should redirect to new page. How should I correct the routing:

```
$routes->connect('/controllerName/actionName/old-slug',
['controller'=>'controllerName','action'=>'actionName','slug'=>'new-slug']);
```

Comment: Do you have some wildcard route being defined before this that's catching the old URL?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Several old pages with slugs are removed and they are backlinked, therefore I need to redirect the traffic into new pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what redirect routes are there for:

```
$routes->redirect(
    '/controllerName/actionName/old-slug', // old
    ['controller' => 'controllerName', 'action' => 'actionName', 'slug' => 'new-slug'], // new
    ['status' => 301] // options
);
```

For better performance I would suggest to redirect at server level instead.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Routing > Redirect Routing](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/routing.html#redirect-routing)**